# Kivy buildozer: toolchain.py: error: the following arguments are required: --package

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Everytime I deploy my app, I delete all the stuff in the folder and I load my Github app project (with the .spec) before `running buildozer -v android release`.

Now I encounter this error: `toolchain.py: error: the following arguments are required: --package`

but I only changed my python code. How is it possible that changing python stuff makes my .apk creation crash ? What could I try to debug this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, you can begin a line with `#` to make a commentary but you can't do put it following a useful line.